# What is the resulting priority between Impact x Effort and Urgency x Importancy Matrices?

Tags: prioritization, matrixed-resources

I'm trying to organize my tasks here in a spreadsheet because of the mobility. I'm trying to prioritize these tasks using 2 matrixes: the impact and effort matrix:
[image]

This would result in a priority1:

```
High impact x low effort: 1
High impact x high effort: 2
Low impact x low effort: 3
Low impact x high effort: 4
```

and the importance and urgency matrix:
[image]

This would result in a priority2 :

```
urgent x important : 1
urgent x not important: 2
not Urgent x Important: 3
not Urgent  x not important: 4
```

Since I'm using a spreadsheet, and the two matrices together will generate another priority list, I would like to know if there is an established priority, between the result of the first matrix `priority1` and the result of the second matrix `priority2`?

Thank you all guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two matrices serve different purposes.

You may apply the urgent x important (Eisenhower) matrix as a "filter". Worth recap some concepts:

- ***Urgent*** is something that cannot wait
- ***Important*** is something aligned to one's goals

With that in mind...

- You'll *always* focus on urgent + important (do now). Hopefully, there isn't many items here (if everything is urgent, nothing is urgent).
- Once you cleaned the 1st queue is when you'll look at not urgent but important (do later). This is where most of your items will appear.
- Urgent items that are not important should be delegated to someone else who considers them important
- Not urgent nor important should be eliminated

Once you apply this filter, you apply the second matrix to "fine tune" the priorities based on their effort x impact.

Answer (score 1):

I would not separate four variables into two priority analyses. I would combine them into a single analysis and create a single prioritized result. I would use a simple choice analysis construct where I would score from 1 to 9 for each variable you identified on those axes. Then I would calculate the result using this formula: (Impact+Important+Urgent/Effort). You can also add a weight value for each variable if you desire. It would look like this:

[image]